# I have to detect a drastic change of intensity within an image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a thermal image of human standing either carrying a cold tool or a hot tool. I want to find the place this tool is. So basically i am trying to make an image processing filter which would give me the area of the place where drastic change of intensity of gray color occurs in the relatively smoother background. I have tried canny edge detector but it gives a lot of noise.

Hot Object To be detected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJeqb.jpg

Cold object to be detected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD9lX.jpg

Comment: Do you have any sample images? How about telling us what Operating System you use and which tools you use?

Comment: I have added sample images

Comment: There are a lot of drastic changes of intensity in those images. You probably need to redefine the task, the current problem statement should find much more than just the circled objects.

Comment: i can segment human out and only run filtering on it.

Comment: The problem can be solved by deploying an IM filter which looks for sudden changes and we can then set the threshold of sudden changes. to avoid noise.

Answer (score 0):

You might increase the Gaussian smoothing kernel to filter out the noise, but that might result in losing out the edges. So in that case you might want to use filter that would preserve the edge and also smooth out the image. Something like [Bilateral filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) could help in that case. It replaces the intensity of each pixel with a weighted average of intensity values from nearby pixels.

Also have you tried different threshold values foe non-max suppression. As that might be helpful when dealing with false positives.

Comment: That just smooths the edges. I am looking for something els.e